# Remote Access to EC2 with a browser

Tags: amazon-ec2

I deploy an Amazon EC2 Ubuntu Linux server but its not accesible through a browser.
I installed a service, specifically Geoserver with it dependancies, however, Firefox could not visit the site. I can ssh into it fruitfully but cant access it with a web browser.

[my rules][1]

Ping returns packets, but i cant access anything on the server apart from ssh.

Ec2 Server: ubuntu 16
Geoserver 2.9

I can come with more clarifications..

Comment: whdetailed at error message does the browser report

Comment: The connection was reset, this if for the public ip.

Comment: Please mask all the instance-id, vpc-id, ip-address , etc before you post the snapshot.